# How to turn while-loops into for-loops?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop, while-loop

How can I formulate these while loops into for loops? I think for loops are nicer looking and want to get rid of these while loops. How do I do that? I have no clue.

````
number_of_vertices = number_of_nodes - 1

nodes_array = np.zeros(number_of_nodes)

starting_number = 7
nodes_array[starting_number - 1] = 1

def find_min():
    min_dist = 10000
    from = -1
    to = -1
    
    i = 0
    while i < len(nodes_array):
        if nodes_array[i] == 1:
            j = 0
            while j < len(nodes_array):
                if min_dist > dist[(i, j)] and dist[(i, j)] != 0 and nodes_array[j] != 1:
                    min_dist = dist[(i, j)]
                    from = i
                    to = j
                j = j+1
        i = i+1
    print("(" + str(from+1) + "," + str(to+1) +"): Distance"+ str(min_dist))
    nodes_array[to] = 1

x = 0
while x < number_of_nodes-1:
    find_min()
    x += 1```
````

Comment: java: for i = 0; i <= node_array.len(); i++ {...}

Comment: @rv.kvetch - This is Python mate.  :-)

Comment: @S3DEV yes, im aware

Comment: The Java loop seems a bit of a random comment then … what have I missed?

Comment: dunno, wanted to add idiomatic approach in another language just for reference. btw, I think approach in javascript is similar to this too.

Comment: @rv.kvetch That's not actually valid Java and wouldn't compile.  The `for` is missing mandatory parens and also needs a type for the index.  Also `<=` should almost certainly be `<`.  And `.len()` would probably be `.size()` or `.length` depending on what type you use for the 'array' (e.g. a `List` or an actual array).  `for(int i = 0; i < node_array.size(); i++) { ... }`

Answer (score 3):

This is equivalent:

```py
i = 0
while i < 10:
    print(i)
    i += 1
```

and

```py
for i in range(10):
    print(i)
```

Comment: @eatmeimadanish it’s `for i in range(len(…)):`.

Comment: So right... my bad.  The healthy way is `for i in nodes_array`